# Build error when attempting to publish to maven local

Tags: gradle, korge

Running into a build issue when attempting to publish my game logic project to maven local:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinMetadata'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':compileKotlinMetadata'
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':metadataCompileClasspath'.
      > Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999.
        Required by:
            project :
         > The consumer was configured to find a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999:
             - iosArm32ApiElements-published
             - iosArm64ApiElements-published
             - iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published
             - iosX64ApiElements-published
             - jsApiElements-published
             - jvmApiElements-published
             - jvmRuntimeElements-published
             - linuxX64ApiElements-published
             - mingwX64ApiElements-published
           All of them match the consumer attributes:
             - Variant 'iosArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm32' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'ir' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares an API of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a runtime of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.klib' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'mingwX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.klib' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'mingw_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
           The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
             - Variant 'iosArm32MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
      > Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999.
        Required by:
            project :
         > The consumer was configured to find a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999:
             - iosArm32ApiElements-published
             - iosArm64ApiElements-published
             - iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published
             - iosX64ApiElements-published
             - jsApiElements-published
             - jvmApiElements-published
             - jvmRuntimeElements-published
             - linuxX64ApiElements-published
             - mingwX64ApiElements-published
           All of them match the consumer attributes:
             - Variant 'iosArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm32' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'ir' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares an API of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a runtime of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.klib' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
             - Variant 'mingwX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Unmatched attributes:
                     - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.klib' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                     - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                     - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'mingw_x64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
           The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
             - Variant 'iosArm32MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
             - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.0.0.999 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common':
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Here's what my build.gradle.kts looks like:

```
val main_class = "CoolMainKt"

project.setProperty("mainClassName", main_class)

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10"
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.benchmark") version "0.4.2"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set(main_class)
}

allOpen {
    annotation("org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State")
}

group = "com.xenotactic.gamelogic"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
}

//val korgeVersion = "2.7.0"
val korgeVersion = "2.0.0.999"
val gitliveVersion = "1.4.3"
val ktorVersion = "2.0.1"

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }


    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:$korgeVersion")
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:$korgeVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-protobuf:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-benchmark-runtime:0.4.2")

                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0")

                compileOnly("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.5")

//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")


                //                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.4")

                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-app:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-database:$gitliveVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-js:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-js:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting
        val nativeMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}

benchmark {
    targets {
        register("jvm")
    }
}
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I finally got it to work after splitting the ktor io/client stuff to it's own kotlin MPP library and updating to the latest kotlin version. Here's the updated gradle file:

```
val main_class = "CoolMainKt"

project.setProperty("mainClassName", main_class)

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.0-RC"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.21"
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.benchmark") version "0.4.2"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set(main_class)
}

allOpen {
    annotation("org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State")
}

group = "com.xenotactic.gamelogic"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
}

//val korgeVersion = "2.7.0"
val korgeVersion = "2.0.0.999"
val gitliveVersion = "1.4.3"
val ktorVersion = "2.0.1"

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }


    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:$korgeVersion")
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:$korgeVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-protobuf:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10")


                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-benchmark-runtime:0.4.2")

//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0")
//                compileOnly("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.5")

//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")


                //                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.4")

                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-app:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:$gitliveVersion")
                //                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-database:$gitliveVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-js:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-js:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting
        val nativeMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}

benchmark {
    targets {
        register("jvm")
    }
}
```